# Docusign Java API unable to get account Id

Tags: java, docusignapi

My code looks like:

```
    ApiClient client = new ApiClient(DEMO_REST_BASEPATH);
    String clientId = "65f9b5d9-XXXX-4de6-ab3c-XXXX";
    java.util.List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
    byte[]  key = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/privateKey"));
    OAuth.OAuthToken token = client.requestJWTApplicationToken(clientId, scopes, key, 3600);
    System.err.println(token.getAccessToken());

    OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = client.getUserInfo(token.getAccessToken());

    System.out.println("UserInfo: " + userInfo);
```

I see I get an auth token back, however I get an error message when trying to get UserInfo:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 401 with response Body: '{"error":"internal_server_error","reference_id":"22e7cf18-74b4-48aa-b916-81bde96071ae"}'
at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.getUserInfo(ApiClient.java:760)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing this line: ([example on GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-java-client/blob/55d490a8b0ff07b293b85b32d9011eb4990a0d54/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java))

```
client.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
```

Your code should be something like this:

```
ApiClient client = new ApiClient(DEMO_REST_BASEPATH);
String clientId = "65f9b5d9-XXXX-4de6-ab3c-XXXX";
java.util.List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
byte[]  key = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/privateKey"));
OAuth.OAuthToken token = client.requestJWTApplicationToken(clientId, scopes, key, 3600);
System.err.println(token.getAccessToken());
client.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = client.getUserInfo(token.getAccessToken());

System.out.println("UserInfo: " + userInfo);
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. I still get the same error message

Comment: what version of the Java package are you using?

Comment: The latest available 3.17.1